# C++ IShellItem from SHCreateItemFromParsingName slow

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to clear log files on multiple servers with  the [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface ([`IFileOperation::DeleteItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775765(v=vs.85).aspx)). The count of the logfiles varies, but can easily exceed 1000. To create the [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144(v=vs.85).aspx) objects which are required I am using [`SHCreateItemFromParsingName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which I noticed is very slow (5-7ms per call). Is there a faster alternative without spawning hundreds of threads parsing the names concurrently? 1000 * 7 are seven seconds, which is definitely too much. I am looking for around half a sec. max.

edit: I can't even parse concurrently because the IFileOperation interface is single threaded only. Solved it by using the older [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx), but still searching a fast alternative for IFileOperation.

Comment: Does `DeleteItem` really delete or move to the trash bin? If it really deletes, why do you use a COM interface and not the Windows API (`DeleteFile`)?

Comment: @WernerHenze It's a Java application (calling C++ with JNI), so I could just call the Java methods to delete the files. I am using the COM interface to increase the user experience. When deleting hundreds of gigabytes of logs on multiple servers, a well known progress bar and all the error managing is a huge gain.